# FFmpeg Decoding AC3 audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I make audio decoding of AC3 format and apply the dynamic range.

```
ffmpeg -i input.ac3  -c:a  -drc_scale 1 output.wav
```

ffmpeg gives an error:

```
unable to find a suitable output format for '1'
1: Invalid argument
```

Please tell me why the option is not applied? Why does the error come out?

Answer (score 1):

Decoder options go before the input name

```
ffmpeg -drc_scale 1 -i input.ac3 output.wav
```

Comment: Thank you!The process started! But But in the process of decoding, a see a yellow message: Estimating duration from bitrate,this may be inaccurate.     How can I clean it?

Comment: You can't. ac3 is a raw stream and has no metadata, so ffmpeg has to estimate duration.

Comment: As far as I understand, this is the standard yellow
message from ffmpeg and it does not affect the result in any way. 
We get 100% correct result. Right?

Comment: That's correct.